# Why configurable:false allows to change writable flag but does'nt for enumerable

Tags: javascript, browser, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I'm writing javascript program to understand how configurable flag set to false effects the property. the program is:

```
let user={
    name:"heman"
};
Object.defineProperty(user, "name",{
    configurable:false
});
try{
    Object.defineProperty(user, "name",{
    configurable:true
    })
}//Throws error
catch(err){console.log(err)}
try{
    Object.defineProperty(user, "name",{
    enumerable:false
    });
} //Throws Error
catch(err){console.log(err)}

try{
    Object.defineProperty(user, "name", {
    writable:false
    });
} //Does'nt Throws Error. But Why?
catch(err){console.log(err)}
```

In this program I first created an object named user, user contains one property i.e, name:"heman". I set configurable flag of name property to false (configurable:false). Then I tried to change the configurable flag again to true It threw an error. After I tried to change the enumerable flag to false which is opposite to it's default value It again threw an error. This time when I tried to change writable flag to false. The flag changed without throwing any error. Even after setting configurable flag to false why is the property still configurable? Why did the writable flag change without throwing any error. I want to know what happens In the below two cases:

1) configurable flag is set to true

2) configurable flag is set to false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why did the writable flag change without throwing any error.

Because the specification allows changing the `writable` flag on a data property from `true` to `false` even if the property's `configurable` property is `false`. Sadly, the spec isn't big on saying *why* things are the way they are, but it's usually very precise about *what* they are. :-)

> I want to know what happens In the below two cases:

Your best bet is to [read through the specification's steps for the operation](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-validateandapplypropertydescriptor).

> 1) configurable flag is set to true

In this case, you can change `writable` from `false` to `true` or from `true` to `false`; the property is fully configurable.

> 2) configurable flag is set to false

The specification allows changing the `writable` flag on a data property from `true` to `false`, but **not** from `false` to `true`.

Comment: I want to clear a doubt. I know that we say that writable, enumerable and configurable are flags. But can we say that value is also a flag

Comment: @user9218974 - No, flags are true/false values.

Comment: @MahdiYounesi - [That](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22243806) was a terrible edit that should never have been approved. It's poor English, gets the name of the field wrong, and removes part of the meaning.

Comment: @tryingToLearn - Please see the comment above.